# Como armazenar e utilizar um vetor no Firebase no Android?

Tags: java, android, array, firebase

Estou com um problema no desenvolvimento do meu app que não consigo resolver e não encontrei algo que me ajudasse. Tal app estava funcionando tranquilamente com dados armazenados em variáveis, mas ao incluir o Firebase tive alguns problemas em armazenar um array.

Fiz um algorítimo em uma classe que recebe e processa dois vetores que, inicialmente, são armazenados em variáveis:[image: Horários armazenados em variáveis]

A ideia é poder armazenar um vetor(array) no firebase e poder utilizá-lo normalmente no meu app, sendo que eu possa utilizar as propriedades do mesmo, como obtenção de valores `array(i)`, tamanho `array.length`, etc...
pois preciso para alimentar outra classe:

```
public class Busca_Horario {

    public String[] timeSelect(String[] entrada1, String[] entrada2){

}
```

Vários tutoriais na internet utilizam comandos do firebase obsoletos e não me serviram. 
Por favor me ajudem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base na resposta do Matheus, segue o meu resultado funcional:

Adicionei uma simples string em uma child no Firebase e utilizei o seguinte comando para buscar esse string e transforma-lo em array do tipo `String[]`.

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String string = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        String[] array = string.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
        System.out.println(array[i]); //Para observar o seu resultado
    }
```

Assim, o método `split()` separa o array a cada vez que encontra a "," (virgula, neste caso, ou qualquer outro termo) em uma posição do array `String[] array`.

Comment: Boa Edeson, fico feliz em ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

O *Firebase* não tem um recurso para distinguir entre uma *`String`* e um *`Array`*, então você terá que criar seus próprios vetores.

Eu geralmente separo os valores utilizando um `;`: `-07:35;07:14;08:25;09:65;.....n`

Então, quando você for buscar estes valores, basta dar um `split` na *`String`* recebida:

```
 String[] valoresFirebase = getFirebaseValues().split(';');
```

Fazendo com que crie seu vetor.